# Clicking on a button based on some text in div

Tags: java, selenium

How can I click on a button based on the text "See More" or "Sign Up"

```
 <div data-reactid=".0.0.$LandingPage.0.1.0.0.1.0.3">
 <button class="arda-button btn -primary" data-reactid=".0.0.$LandingPage.0.1.0.0.1.0.3.$main-menu-see-more">See More</button>
  <button class="arda-button btn -primary" data-reactid=".0.0.$LandingPage.0.1.0.0.1.0.3.$main-menu-sign-up">Sign Up</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Or based on the html above can you see a unique way of identifying and clicking on the two buttons?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPATH ( Consider the Xpath is not big and Ugly) where each button will be separate.

If XPATH is ugly and long use regular Expression where data-reactid CONTAINS "main-menu-see-more" for "See More" button. And data-reactid CONTAINS main-menu-sign-up for Sign up button

```
"//*[contains(@data-reactid,'main-menu-see-more')]"

 " //*[contains(@data-reactid,'main-menu-sign-up')]"
```

What about linked Text "See More" and "Sign Up".

Please share your feedback its working not......

Comment: Thanks. Will try this soon and let you know. Appreciate you helping with my questions today. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Identify using contains text() as 'see more' and 'sign up', should work.

By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'See More')]")
By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Sign Up')]")

Comment: @ratsstack : Please accept if answer worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I avoid XPath like the plague unless absolutely necessary because it's complicated, slower than other methods, and more prone to breaking (in general). I would do this using a CSS Selector.

The `data-reactid` is unique for each of these elements so I would use those to find the desired elements instead of the text.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[data-reactid='.0.0.$LandingPage.0.1.0.0.1.0.3.$main-menu-see-more']")).click();
```

This code finds a `button` that has the specified `data-reactid` and clicks it.

CSS Selectors are very powerful and it lets you avoid XPath... which is a good thing. :)

[CSS Selector reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)